# Does equality of metric outer measures with restriction to Borel sets imply equality of metric outer measures themselves?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu_i^*\colon 2^{[0,1]}\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ be a metric outer measure ($i=1,2$). Fix $i$. It is known that a family $\Sigma_i$ of all $\mu_i^*$-measurable sets (i.e. all sets $C\subset [0,1]$ such that $\mu^*_i(A)=\mu^*_i(A\cap C)+\mu^*_i(A \setminus C)$ for all $A\subset [0,1]$) forms a $\sigma$-algebra. Moreover, $\mu_i^*|_{\Sigma_i}$ is a measure. Since $\mu_i^*$ is a metric outer measure, if $B([0,1])$ is the $\sigma$-algebra of all Borel subsets of $[0,1]$ then $B([0,1])\subset \Sigma_i$.

Assume that the measures $\mu_1^*|_{B([0,1])},\mu_2^*|_{B([0,1])}$ are equal, i.e. $\mu_1^*|_{B([0,1])}=\mu_2^*|_{B([0,1])}$. Does it imply that $\mu_1^*=\mu_2^*$?

Comment: Will it even imply that the set of measurable sets is the same?